# Sorting related arrays with no data reference point

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I've using the Chart.js library to visualise some data. I've counted instances so types and stored them in an object like so. The problem is that I now wish to sort these values but have no point of reference from which to do so.

Chart.js takes the labels and data and separate arrays, and as such this was the solution I came up with. It works great until you wish to sort the data. The first label is for the first data, etc.

What would be a better solution?

```
var apertures = { "labels": ["example", "exmple"], "data": [4, 18] }
```

I'd like store the data with the label but I don't know how to make Chart.js do the magic like that.

```
var chartAperture = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: apertures.labels,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Dataset 1',
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,225,0,0.5)",
          borderColor: "#ffe100",
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: apertures.data
      }]
    } ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean that, before sorting, the first label corresponds to the first data?

Comment: @ThéophilePace I do

Comment: How do you want to sort them? By growing order I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would do that in a three step process.

Step 1: create an Array, that has objects of label/value:

```
var step1 = apertures.labels.map(function (label, idx) {
  return { label: label, value: apertures.data[idx] }
});
```

Step 2: sort that:

```
var step2 = step1.sort(function (i1, i2) { 
  //i1 - i2 or i2 - i1 determines acceding or descending order 
  return i1.value - i2.value;
});
```

Step 3: restore the object:

```
var step3 = step2.reduce(function (result, item) {
  result.labels.push(item.label);
  result.data.push(item.value);
  return result;
}, { labels: [], data: [] })
```

You can chain that like so:

```
var step3 = apertures.labels
  .map(<function step 1>)
  .sort(<function step 2>)
  .reduce(<function step 3>);
```

Comment: I got excited about using map but then `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at step2.reduce.lables`

Comment: It will work like that, let me have a look for the mistake…

Comment: fixed, two typos…

Comment: haha I am going to go insane https://i.imgur.com/04tPThL.jpg
how is this not working

Comment: the typo is in step3, `labels` …

Answer (score 0):

I think,
this would be the better option to write own function to sort the data for chart.js.

you can refer below:

Here **data.sort** function is use for sorting the data,

Comment: Looked great but the functions are based on version 1 of the library and things have been moved around a fair bit in the chart object.

Answer (score 0):

You must sort your table data and return the new indices instead of the values. Then you just have to push the indexed values in a new apertures object and return it. See the below example :

```js
const apertures = { "labels": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], "data": [4, 18, 0, 345, 1] }

function sortByIncreasingOrder({ labels, data }) {
    const newIndices = new Array(data.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < newIndices.length; i++)
        newIndices[i] = i

    //I have no idea how you want to sort them.
    // Because I'm not an artist, we're going to use <
    //but you can use your own
    myPersonnalOrder = (a, b) => (data[a] < data[b]) ? -1 : 1

    
    newIndices.sort(myPersonnalOrder)
    console.log("New indices : " + newIndices)
    const sortedApertures = { "labels": [], "data": [] }
    newIndices.forEach((value, index) => {
        sortedApertures.labels[index] = apertures.labels[value]
        sortedApertures.data[index] = apertures.data[value]
    })
    return sortedApertures
}

console.log(sortByIncreasingOrder(apertures))
```